# How to write 'for loop' with multiple conditions for a dataframe with 60 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q5JV.png)

For the df in the image, how do I find the number of instances for each column (eg:151) where the value of that column is <= 0 and value of "WS" column is > 0 ("WS" > 0 will be a constant "AND" with all the other columns - 151, 154, 152). So basically 151 <= 0 and WS > 0, 152 <= 0 and WS > 0.. and so on.
How to write a for loop for this? The output needs to be stored in another df which would look something like (just random numbers)-

151 - 2368
152 - 3098
154 - 2301

Comment: Could you include the dataframe in the question and not as a link to an image of it?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
In particular, off-site links and images of text are not acceptable.

Comment: df= {151: [-0.1, -0.3, 3, 7 ],
        152: [-3, -5, 14, -0.1],
'WS': [0, 3, 0, 5]
        }
some of the values, there are 22k rows and 60 other columns like 152 and 151.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the rows of a dataframe, you can use the `itterrows()` method:

```
cols = df.columns[:-1] ##[151, 154, 152]
out = pd.Series({c: 0 for c in cols})
for c in cols:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row[c] <= 0 and row['WS'] > 0:
            out[c] = out[c] + 1
```

There is, however, a better way to do this (without iterating over the rows), by checking the length of the dataframe when it's filtered according to these conditions:

```
cols = df.columns[:-1] ##[151, 154, 152]
out = pd.Series()
for c in cols:
    out[c] = len(df[(df[c] <= 0)&(df['WS'] > 0)])
```

Here `cf[c] <= 0` gives us a column of binary values indicating there rows where column `c` is less than 0. Likewise `df['WS'] > 0` is a binary column indicating which rows have positive values for WS. `(df[c] <= 0)&(df['WS'] > 0)` gives us a column indicating the rows where both are true, and slicing a dataframe by a binary column like `df[binary_column]` gives us a dataframe of only the rows where that binary column was true.

Comment: Thabnks Jaob! :)